# vba match method for strings unexpected result

Tags: excel, vba, find, match

I am using Application.WorksheetFunction.Match method for looking a string in a range. It gives me the rows that contain different string values.

I thought it maybe due to space, but not it is for sure not space in a string not in the worksheet cell value. When I try with rng.Find method it gives me the wanted result. But why I am not using the Find method because, there is a cell in which the word that I am using is there already. The find method goes for that row.

When I delete that duality giving row value  for testing find method it gives expected result.

Match is not case sensitive, but finds the values that are totally different. And playing with 0, -1,1 does not differ the result.
What can be reason for such stupid result?

the value inside cells are:

Column "A" (let's assume):rng

1. Net profit margin
2. - profit margin

the code

```vb
b=    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("net profit",rng,0)
a=    rng.Find("net profit")
```

These are samples, otherwise I cannot share, because there are different function callings from different procedures.

Comment: There's no way we can help if you don't provide specific information, including sample values which are "wrongly" matched, and the code you're using.

Comment: Tim Williams, I think I am lost in exact matching issues with find and match methods. I tried Find(MatchCase:=True), but it also gives another word expression. Wasn't the match.method with 0 expression for exact matching, if not it should give an error. Maybe I need to try WorksheetFunction.Find it is case sensitive and exact matching

Comment: `application.match("Net profit*",[A:A],0)` will match anything that is exactly "Net porfit" or which starts with that string.  But you have not explained what "It gives me the rows that contain different string values." means - what other values are returned other than what you're trying to match?